# How to match two characters with regex

Tags: javascript, regex

This is what I want to match inside of a textarea:

`@`+any character to perform an autocomplete operation to find for users when the `@` is called and a character is added next to it as the term.

this is the textarea

```
<textarea></textarea>
```

this is the js:

```
function strpos (haystack, needle, offset) {
  var i = (haystack + "").indexOf(needle, (offset || 0));
  return i === -1 ? false : i;
}

var dauto=function(){
  if(strpos($(this).val(),"@ "+reg_exhere)!==false){
    alert("match found");
  }
}

$("textarea").bind("keyup",dauto);
$("textarea").bind("keydown",dauto);
```

Now I really don't know what to use as the regular expression in there, plus I don't know if using it in there would help as it would loose the look up for the @ before any character so the following string would return true:

`@ mystring`

as whereas I only need to find:

`@anycharacterhere`

Have tried with

```
$(this).val().match(/^\+@\*+$/);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `String#match()` with the simple regex `/@(\w+)/`

```
var dauto = function(){
  $( '#capture' ).html($( this ).val().match(/@(\w+)/)[1]);
}

$("textarea").bind("keyup",dauto);
$("textarea").bind("keydown",dauto);
```

Test with the following HTML block

```
<textarea></textarea>
<p id="capture"></p>
```

Working Demo at **[JsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/FfJKV/1/)** *(try typing "hi @username" there)*

Comment: Use [this](http://jsfiddle.net/FfJKV/2/) one if anyone wants to allow for multiple `@`s in their text content like `To @John, From @Jane`.

Comment: this is awesome, how would I just let them type @ John Fraser, @ Jane Thompson in there, allow for multiple white spaces to still capture the characters .

Comment: @Ibennet you can do that with `(.+)` instead but I don't think it's a good idea because the capture won't stop matching then. That's why Twitter, SO etc. don't match them either. Same goes for Twitter #HashTags too.

Comment: great, Facebook is taking @User Name Continued on the search, but it should get stopped at the next @ with the given code, I'm implementing this now. Thanks

Comment: @lbennet Okay, glad you could fit this to your requirements. +1 for the question.